# how to create a ad hoc distribution file?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, app-store

I only have the UDID of the device and I want to create a ad hoc distribution file. I have a developer account on apple. So help me on this:-

1. Do I need a iOS device to create a app file? if no, then how can I
   do that?
2. Can I use my clients UDID for provision file without connecting to
   my machine?
3. The procedure of creating a provision file.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=ad+hoc+distribution+file

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need an iDevice for creating the ipa file
2. You can use the UDID for provision without connecting it to your device
3. For creating a provisioning profile refer [CreatingandDownloadingDevelopmentProvisioningProfiles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandDownloadingDevelopmentProvisioningProfiles/CreatingandDownloadingDevelopmentProvisioningProfiles.html)

F**or creating an ipa for testing it on device:**

1. Create provisioning profile :[Create Provisioning profile](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-an-apple-development-provisioning-pr.html)
2. Create the development certificate and install it
3. Archive your application [Ipa Creation](http://diaryofacodemonkey.ruprect.com/2011/03/18/ad-hoc-app-distribution-with-xcode-4/)

A good [tutorial](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/iphone/9781449394004/preparing-your-iphone/creating_a_development_certifi#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODE0NDkzOTQwMDQlMkYxMQ==) for you.